# Change Style of GridView Select Button

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a `GridView` with selection enabled. I'd like to programmatically change the style of these links, but I'm not sure how to access them. I've applied CSS to them using the `a` selector, but I can't do this through the code.

How can I modify the appearance of these buttons using C#?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUserInfo" runat="server" 
    onrowdatabound="gvUserInfo_RowDataBound1">
 <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" runat="server" Text="Link"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>



protected void gvUserInfo_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lnk = e.Row.FindControl("lnkButton") as LinkButton;
            lnk.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I grid view is a Table you can use CSS

```
<html>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RegNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="931px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="170px" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True">
</asp:GridView>
<style>
    td > a {
        /*button*/
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
        touch-action: manipulation;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        /*button color*/
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #c71c22;
        border-color: #c71c22;
    }

        td > a:hover {
            color: #555555;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #9a161a;
            border-color: #911419;
        }
```